# Fingerprint sensor Arduino IDE code errors (Arduino Uno)

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

This code is for a fingerprint sensor. I keep getting the "function definition is not allowed before '{' token" error on the Arduino IDE. Any further corrections would also be immensely appreciated.

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("fingertest");
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);



  // set the data rate for the sensor serial port
  finger.begin(57600);

  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1) { delay(1); }


  finger.getTemplateCount();
  Serial.print("Sensor contains "); Serial.print(finger.templateCount); Serial.println(" templates");
  Serial.println("Waiting for valid finger...");
}

void loop()                     // run over and over again

{
  getFingerprintIDez();
  delay(50);            //don't ned to run this at full speed.
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
}

uint8_t getFingerprintID() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println("No finger detected");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;


  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;


  // OK converted!
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Found a print match!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND) {
    Serial.println("Did not find a match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   

  // found a match!
  Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID); 
  Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence); 

  return finger.fingerID;
}

// returns -1 if failed, otherwise returns ID #
int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  p = finger.image2Tz();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  // found a match!


  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);

  Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID); 
  Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence);
  return finger.fingerID; 
}
```

Here is the circuit diagram-
[image]
This program works for products like- https://www.flyrobo.in/finger_print_sensor
.The wire connection is as follows- fingerprint sensor white wire - pin 3, yellow wire - pin 2, red wire - “+5v” , black wire - “GND” servo wire - pin 4

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: check the braces `{}` ....  make sure that they all match .... it helps to copy and paste your code into a text editor such as notepad++ and use it to count the braces .... https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Hint: Look at else block in setup and at your loop function